# I cant link my ps4 account to my pc account

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I made a pc account and I wanted to link my ps4 skins to it. When I try to link it it says this account is already linked to (account names) account. Please help.

Comment: I had this issue also. Try checking your linked accounts on the Epic Games website on your computer.

Comment: Im sorry but this did not work. I looked at the epic games page where i went to link it and it says connect. when i click this button it says my ps4 account is linked to another account i do not know how to enter. can i disconnect it through my ps4.